# Cross matching 2 collections using Linq .Any

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to cross match 2 collections against eachother using Linq. I have an array of characters corresponding to letters of the alphabet and I want to know if any string from a given collection starts with any of those letters. I thought this should have worked but I'm returning false in at least one case where I know it shouldn't:

```
bool isMatch = stringCollection.Any(stringValue => {
   return characterArray.Any(letter => stringValue[0].ToString().ToUpper() 
   == letter.ToString()); 
});
```

The characters in characterArray are all upper case which is why I'm doing the string manipulations instead of just comparing characters. Am I missing something simple or can someone help me fix this statement?

Comment: Perhaps you're having a mismatch on cultures?  Maybe, take a look at `ToUpperInvariant()`

Comment: can you provide an example that doesnt give the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about stripping your strings down to a collection of upper-case characters, then using LINQ's `Intersect()` method?

```
bool isMatch = stringCollection.Select(s => Char.ToUpper(s[0]))
  .Distinct()
  .Intersect(characterArray).Any();
```

Comment: Thanks didn't know about the Intersect method, this is exactly what I was looking for